# Angular Service injected not working

Tags: angularjs

I have created and injected the service(myService) into my app (app) , but it is not working. The error implies that I have not defined the service anywhere:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:  myServiceProvider <- myService <- myController

myService calls another service - ajaxService to do the actual http call.

The only reason I would think that myService throws the above error when trying to call it in myController is because I have another module defined in the app definition (**common.components**). This module has its own separate services which I am using elsewhere in my app. I am wondering if the app is searching for a definition of myService within that the common.components module instead of inside itself.
Here is my code:

**- app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app ', ['ngRoute','common.components']);
```

**- myService.js**

```
var serviceId = 'myService';
angular.module('app').service(serviceId,['$q','ajaxService','$log',myService]);

function myService($q, ajaxService, $log){
    var states = [];
    this.getStates = function() {
        var defered = $q.defer(); 
        ajaxService.getStates().then(function(result){
            states = result.data;
            defered.resolve(states);
        },
        function(error){
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return defered.promise;


    };

}
```

**- ajaxService.js**

```
var serviceId = 'ajaxService';
angular.module('app',[]).service(serviceId,['$http','$log',ajaxService]);

function ajaxService($http,$log){
  this.getStates = function() {
        return $http.get('./json/DATA.json');
  };   

}
```

- **myController.js**

(function(){
'use strict';

```
angular.module('app').controller('myController',['$scope','$log','myService',myController]);

function myController($scope,$log,myService){ 

    $scope.states = [];

    myService.getStates().then(function(states){
        $scope.states = states;
    });            
}
```

})();

I have been trying to find out what is wrong for hours, but I am lost. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my answer as you have now provided more info.

Your issue is in your ajaxService.js

Change this line

```
angular.module('app',[]).service(serviceId,['$http','$log',ajaxService]);
```

to this

```
angular.module('app').service(serviceId,['$http','$log',ajaxService]);
```

Your are recreating the app module by adding the [].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is basically suggesting that I have to define the service within the common.components module. But what if i wanted the service to be defined within 'app' itself and referenced from there. NOT FROM WITHIN the common.components module.

Comment: I have made changes to my original question to make you better understand what I need. And i have renamed shipToService to myService.